# How to remove all PHP array elements containing a certain sub-string?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, higher-order-functions

ok i looked up some functions and i don't seem to lucky of finding any,

i wanna filter an array to strip specific array that contains some string

heres an example :

```
$array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March',);
$to_remove = "Jan"; // or jan || jAn, .. no case sensitivity
$strip = somefunction($array, $to_remove);
print_r($strip);
```

it should return

```
[1] => February
[2] => March
```

a function that looks for the sub-string for all values in an array, if the sub-string is found, remove that element from the array

Comment: http://php.net/array_filter? PHP's functions are pretty easy to find, and named after what they do...

Comment: after 7 questions one of them at least must of had an acceptable answer.

Comment: @marc yes but php doesn't has that much info about this function, i want to see how it works like how i want it above

Comment: The linked PHP doc page has plenty of examples on how to use the function.

Comment: several dozen examples on the manual page, what more do you want?

Comment: yup but it looks so long and my laziness won't read all this thing lol, can someone use that function with the example i wrote, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://co.php.net/array_filter) and [stripos](http://co.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
$array = array(1 => 'January', 'February', 'March');
print_r(array_filter($array, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, 'Jan') === false); }));
```

Comment: By using the stripos function, you should not have to worry about case sensitivity.

Comment: one last question, how to only returns arrays that contains a specific string ?

Comment: Then Change the `=== false` with `!== false`. In this case `return (stripos($var, 'fEb') !== false)`.

Comment: Hey, i have a question for you. Instead of making a new question i shall first try my luck here. What you wrote works perfectly however, how can i make it to specificly delete 'a' for example. Because if i run it like this it will also delete array entries which are `apple` or `banana`. If you don't mind be asking another question. What if the words im looking for is in an array named $common_words. So instead of just 'Jan' in your example I have a whole array of words.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) with a [closure](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) (inline-function):

```
array_filter(
  $array,
  function ($element) use ($to_remove) {
    return strpos($element, $to_remove) === false;
  }
);
```

(PHP Version >= 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with `array_filter`. This function receives the array to filter and a callback function that does the actual filtering based on the value received:

```
function filter_func( $v )
{
  return ( ( $var % 2 ) == 0 );
}
$test_array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 );
print_r( array_filter( $test_array, "filter_func" ) );
```

Hope helped!