# Remove array element based on its character length

Tags: php, arrays, unset, strlen, array-unset

I have an array in `PHP` as:

```
$array = array("Linda","Chadwick","Bari","Angela","Marco");
```

Therefore,

```
 $array[0]="Linda"  
 $array[1]="Chadwick"  
 $array[2]="Bari"  
 $array[3]="Angela"  
 $array[4]="Marco"
```

I want to remove the names having string length `<=4`.

So that, the keys are adjusted.

```
$array[0]="Linda"
$array[1]="Chadwick"  
$array[2]="Angela"  
$array[3]="Marco"
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591094/how-do-you-reindex-an-array-in-php) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474216/php-how-to-filter-an-array-that-contains-something).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use it using `array_filter` only along with `strlen`

```
$array = array("Linda","Chadwick","Bari","Angela","Marco");
$result = array_filter($array,function($v){ return strlen($v) > 4; });
print_r($result);

$result = array();
array_walk($array,function($v) use (&$result){ if(strlen($v) > 4){$result[] = $v;} });
print_r($result);
```

[**array_filter**](https://eval.in/377248)

[**array_walk**](https://eval.in/377248)

Comment: it wasn't me that downvoted, but in your output the indexes go like 0,1,3,4 instead of 0,1,2,3 like requested. Therefore I used `array_values` after `array_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for that I'll make some changes to accomplish that thanks @n-dru

Comment: Thank you for your effort but Jack's code is working for me. 

`$array = array_values(array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return strlen($v) > 4;`

Comment: @SaifUrRahman I've another answer too in which your key indexes will be as you needed and I appreciate that answer too

Comment: I just need the keys to be auto adjusted, when the elements are removed.

Answer (score 5):

Use `array_filter` and then `array_values` to reset the keys sequence:

```
$array = array("Linda","Chadwick","Bari","Angela","Marco");
$array = array_values(array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return strlen($v) > 4;
}));
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Linda [1] => Chadwick [2] => Angela [3] => Marco )
```

Comment: `<?php

$array = array("Linda","Chadwick","Bari","Angela","Marco");
echo "BEFORE:";
echo "<br>";

$c=count($array);
echo "NUMBER OF ELEMENTS:".$c;
echo "<br>";
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++)
{

echo "INDEX".$i."=";
echo $array[$i];
echo "<br>";
}

 $array = array_values(array_filter($array, function($v){if(strlen($v)>4){return $v;}}));

echo "AFTER:";
echo "<br>";

$c=count($array);
echo "NUMBER OF ELEMENTS:".$c;
echo "<br>";

for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++)
{

echo "INDEX".$i."=";
echo $array[$i];
echo "<br>";
}

?>`