# How to create multiple array functions at a time?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array exp :

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://openload.co/f/duLIXdarHEM/RARBG.txt
    [1] => https://openload.co/f/C7D4l55xXn8/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.idx
    [2] => https://openload.co/f/9fap6xaoJjQ/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.sub
    [3] => https://openload.co/f/zE7ztog0j9U/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.jpg
    [4] => https://openload.co/f/wjF657ljkVg/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.mkv.mp4
    [5] => https://openload.co/f/4B0qD5ab5bU/Payback.Straight.Up.2006.DC.BRRip.XviD.MP3-XVID.avi
    [6] => https://openload.co/f/4B0qD5ab5bU/Payback.Straight.Up.2006.DC.BRRip.sample.XviD.MP3-XVID.avi
    [7] => https://openload.co/f/b1ihEIUgdDA/2_Eng.srt
)
```

How can I create a function to get links containing ".mp4", ".avi", ".mkv", ...
and delete the links that contain the words ".txt" ".jpg" ".sample", .....
and bring it back to a new continuous array

Comment: Not recommended to use smilies in the questions.

Comment: loop thru it, check the link with a regex and if it matches then add link to new array, keep new array when done.  this isn't a code writing service - we'll help you fix the code that you wrote...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all PHP array elements containing a certain sub-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474216/how-to-remove-all-php-array-elements-containing-a-certain-sub-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Using strpos:**

```
$array = ['https://openload.co/f/duLIXdarHEM/RARBG.txt',
          'https://openload.co/f/C7D4l55xXn8/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.idx', 
          'https://openload.co/f/9fap6xaoJjQ/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.sub', 
          'https://openload.co/f/zE7ztog0j9U/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.jpg', 
          'https://openload.co/f/wjF657ljkVg/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.mkv.mp4'];  

$result = array_filter($array, function($x) {     
    return (strpos($x, '.avi') || strpos($x, '.mp4') || strpos($x, '.mkv'));    
});  
print_r($result);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a=['https://openload.co/f/duLIXdarHEM/RARBG.txt','https://openload.co/f/b1ihEIUgdDA/2_Eng.srt','https://openload.co/f/4B0qD5ab5bU/Payback.Straight.Up.2006.DC.BRRip.XviD.MP3-XVID.avi'];

$b = array_filter($a, function($v){return preg_match("/(\.mp4){1}|(\.avi){1}|(\.mkv){1}/", $v);});

var_dump($b);
```

You can run check the result [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67c5ec3f1072dcf130aef0a95dd175ad6c3ccc5a)

Answer (score 0):

since you are going to bring the needed links back to another array anyway, why dont you just delete the not needed links from the original array and reindex it, you can accomplish that by:

```
`<?php
$array = array( 
"https://openload.co/f/duLIXdarHEM/RARBG.txt",  
"https://openload.co/f/C7D4l55xXn8/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.idx", 
"https://openload.co/f/9fap6xaoJjQ/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.sub", 
"https://openload.co/f/zE7ztog0j9U/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264-sparks.jpg",      
"https://openload.co/f/wjF657ljkVg/the.predator.2018.1080p.bluray.x264- 
 sparks.mkv.mp4",  
"https://openload.co/f/4B0qD5ab5bU/Payback.Straight.Up.2006.DC.BRRip.XviD.MP3- 
 XVID.avi",
"https://openload.co/f/4B0qD5ab5bU/Payback.Straight.Up.2006.DC.BRRip.sample.XviD.MP3- 
 XVID.avi", 
"https://openload.co/f/b1ihEIUgdDA/2_Eng.srt" );

foreach( $array as $arr ){
if(preg_match('/^.*\.(jpg|txt|sample|)$/i', $arr)){
unset($array[array_search($arr, $array)]);// delete the element
$newArray = array_values($array);// reindex array
}
}

print_r($newArray);`
```

you can see it in action [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f67fc6794fe661790dd2da418ce07fa661e900e8)